# In tkinter, is it possible to place the same widget into multiple frames?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a UI with ttk.Notebook tabs, and would like to display the same widget in multiple tabs. This requires the widget to simultaneously have multiple parent frames, which doesn't seem possible. Is there some other way it can be done?

Comment: can you show your attempts...

Comment: Please see below, but I'm not sure (a) that it will work under all circumstances and (b) that there isn't some simpler way of getting a widget to display on multiple notebook tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have since tinkered around with this problem, and have come up with this preliminary (and largely untested) solution to having a widget appear on multiple tabs of a `ttk.Notebook`.

Although the physical parent of a widget is immutably set when the widget is created, its geometric parent (which controls where it appears) CAN be changed using the `.grid()` `in_` option. So in theory it should be possible to have the widget appear on multiple notebook tabs simply by changing its geometric parent whenever the user changes to a new tab (`NotebookTabChanged`)

The following code seems to work as advertised, although I haven't really tested it outside the toy code below:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

class myApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):

        super().__init__()

        # Create the Notebook and bind the tab-select event 
        self.notebook = ttk.Notebook(self, width=500, height=200)
        self.notebook.grid()
        self.notebook.bind("<<NotebookTabChanged>>", self.select_tab)

        # Create a status bar which displays the name of the currently selected tab 
        self.status = ttk.Label(self)
        self.status.grid(sticky='w')

        # Create three frames - one for each of three tabs - and store them in 
        # a dictionary with the tab names as keys
        self.tabs = dict()
        self.tabs['PAGE 1'] = ttk.Frame(self.notebook)
        self.tabs['PAGE 2'] = ttk.Frame(self.notebook)
        self.tabs['PAGE 3'] = ttk.Frame(self.notebook)

        # Create the tabs in the notebook
        for t in self.tabs.keys():
            self.notebook.add(self.tabs[t], text=t, underline=0, sticky='nsew')

        # Put a widget on the middle tab, just to have soemthing there
        ttk.Label(self.tabs['PAGE 2'],text="A SIMPLE LABEL").grid(row=0,column=0)
    
        # Create a button - this is the widget we wish to appear on all tabs
        self.btn = tk.Button(self,text='PRESS ME!',command=self.button_pressed)


    # This is the method called when the user selectes a new tab. It 
    # updates the status bar and moves the button to the new tab.
    
    def select_tab(self, event):
        id = self.notebook.select()
        name = self.notebook.tab(id, "text")
        text = f"--- {name} is currently selected ---"
        self.status.config(text=text)
        self.btn.grid(row=4,column=0,in_= self.tabs[name])


    def button_pressed(self):
        print('BUTTON PRESSED')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = myApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Yes, you can _move_ a widget to a different parent. They cannot "simultaneously have multiple parent frames" as you wrote in your question.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot have a single widget in multiple places. A widget can only be in one place at a time.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. But is there some other way it can be done, besides duplicating the widget so it can be placed on two separate tabs?

Comment: @mkam: Like the answer says, there is no way to put one widget in multiple places. You can have the same _data_ in multiple places, but not the same _widget_.

Comment: As you say, a widget cannot have two different masters, as it is just a node in a tree. But the geometrical parent of a widget does not have to be the same as the parent under which the widget was created - the documentation for the .grid() in_ option says that "To register w as a child of some widget w2, use in_=w2. The new parent w2 must be a descendant of the parent widget used when w was created." I think therein lies the trick to have a widget appear on more than one tab.

Comment: @mkam: The documentation is correct that a widget can be placed in some other widget than its direct parent. That still does not change the fact that a widget cannot appear in more than one place at the same time. Of that I am 100% certain.

Comment: @Brian Oakley: You are completely correct, of course. But with notebooks, only one tab is ever shown at any one time, so it should be possible to move the widget about from tab to tab when the user selected a new tab.

Comment: @mkam: yes, that is possible. That's not what the question asked, however.

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted to know - whether there is some other way (other than having multiple parents, which didn't seem possible to me) of displaying a widget in multiple notebook tabs.

Comment: @mkam: the answer remains that you can't display a widget in multiple tabs. You can show it in only one tab at a time.

Comment: @Brian Oakley: Too true - but you can only display one tab at a time in a ttk.Notebook anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, example using two notebook tabs(aba1, aba2)

```
def widgets_with_icon(self):

    aba=''
    abas = (self.aba1, self.aba2)
    
    for aba in abas:
        self.tkimage3 = PhotoImage(file="images/salvar_100.png")

        self.bt_image_save = tk.Button(aba, image=self.tkimage3, compound=tk.LEFT, bd=0, bg='#A9A9A9', activebackground='#A9A9A9', command=your_command)
        
        self.bt_image_save.image = self.tkimage3 # reference to image not garbage collect
        self.bt_image_save.place(relx=0.01, rely=0.01, relwidth=0.03, relheight=0.04)
```

self.bt_image_save (button with image only) will appear in aba1 and aba2.
I hope it can help.